# Facebook open graph - login button not displaying everytime

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently upgraded to open graph and implemented some of the facebook social plugins on my website like fb:friendpile  fb:like-box etc

Ever since I implemented these new features, I'm seeing some random behavior with these plugins.

Like on my home page, when you type in the URL and go for the first time, none of the facebook social plugins are rendered - no login button, no friendpile no like - nothing.

But when you hit CTRL F5 - they appear. First I thought it probably has somethin to do with my machine but yesterday two of my users reported the same issue.

I googled around and it seems to have something to do with where you place your connect code. Right now, I have this relevant portion of the script placed in my head tag - I even tried placing it right before the end of body tag - but it made no difference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({appId: '<?php echo Zend_Registry::getInstance()->configuration->facebook->appid;?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

                /* All the events registered */
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    // do something with response
                    login();
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                    // do something with response
                    logout();
                });
            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                e.src = document.location.protocol +
                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                e.async = true;
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());

            function login(){        
                document.location.href = "<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/login/log";
            }
            function logout(){
                FB.init({appId: '<?php echo Zend_Registry::getInstance()->configuration->facebook->appid;?>'});               
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                      // user is now logged out
                    }); 
                document.location.href = "<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/login/logout";
                return false;
            }
</script>
```

Any insights in trouble shooting this will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Where is your `FB.init()`? Can you post your full init script?

Comment: Thanks - I have updated the question to show the full init script

Comment: And you have `<div id="fb-root"></div>` above this, right? Fb init code you provided should be put right below open `<body>` tag. Also do you include `xmlns:fb` namespace in `<html>` tag?

Comment: Yes - after the body tag - I immediately have the <div id="fb-root"></div> followed by code shown above.

Comment: Everything looks fine... Have you tried looking in firebug what is going on with those fbml tags on the page - do they remain as fbml or getting rendered into something that is hidden?

Comment: Actually your logout method doesn't look good. Why do you init FB there for the second time? That might be the problem. That method will be called when user is already logged out, you don't have to log them out yourself.

Comment: I removed the FB.init in the logout method - should I also remove the FB.logout(function response) {}

Comment: I think so, it is a callback method that is called after a user got logged out. You would need to call `FB.logout` if you want to logout a user yourself (after clicking on your own logout link for example).

Comment: well I call the logout method also when user clicks on the logout link on my page. I tried by removing those lines and I'm still having the same issue - I can consistently repeat it on Chrome - its like it renders the page quickly and times out before calling facebook or something cos in the status bar - I will see something like "waiting for ah8.facebook.com" then nothin appears - second time when I hit refresh - it will appear - but in IE and Firefox -its sporadic sometimes it works the first time also

Comment: I don't know then what's the problem, sorry. Facebook can act funny sometimes. Try to figure out what exactly times out with firebug and check if fb init is actually being called. Another option would be disabling auto fbml parsing in FB.init and trying to render FBML manually by calling `FB.XFBML.parse()`, but that might not work either. And about logout method - if you need to do manual logout then just create another method and call FB.logout there (but still no need for second FB.init).

Answer (score 1):

Your logout logic seems problematic (you call `FB.logout()` in `logout()` -- but also call `logout()` on the 'auth.logout' event, which seems circular). You should also remove the `FB.init()` call inside your `logout()` function. The lack of `xmlns:fb` on the `<html>` tag is often the cause of XFBML not rendering in IE, so I'd double check that. You could also try replacing the async loading with sync loading using a normal script tag like:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

But a live repro case would be more helpful since your code looks fine for the most part.

EDIT: You can also checkout http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:login-button for examples.

Comment: Thanks daaku - based on the comments from serg and you , I did correct my logout logic and I did double check the xmlnb:fb in the html tag. I will try the sync loading but I made one other change and this problem has stopped occuring. I'm still not 100% sure if its because of that.

I was using facebook ads and as part of beta testing facebook provided with the tracking code they asked to insert at the bottom of the page. I removed it 2 days back and the problem seems to have gone away. I'm goin to wait for another couple of days to see if I can reproduce that error.

Thanks

Comment: Cool -- feel free to file an issue on Github or report the issue thru the ads feedback if you notice it again. A repro case is always helpful too :)